# Adding function to sidebar menu on Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, uiviewcontroller, sidebar

So I just did a tutorial on adding a blurry sidebar menu. I replicated the code but I cant seem to find out how to call my other ViewControllers I made in storyboard mode.

I have created files and linked them to `UIViewControllers`. But when I try to call that ViewController with my sidebar menu I'm getting a black screen.

Here is the link of the files I used to follow along http://goo.gl/ULWxJh 
And here is the link of the youtube video I followed along with http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qaLiZgUK2T0

Not sure why! Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, SideBarDelegate {

    var sideBar:SideBar = SideBar()         // Side Bar


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        // Side bar action and text
       sideBar = SideBar(sourceView: self.view, menuItems: ["Home", "Business Directory", "Classifieds", "Featured News", "Jobs", "Restaurants", "Sports"])
       sideBar.delegate = self

    }

    // Side Bar funcion
    func sideBarDidSelectButtonAtIndex(index: Int) {
          if index == 0{
             let vc = ViewController()
             self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
          }else if index == 1{
             let vc = businessDirectoryVC()
             self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)

          }    
    }
}
```

Comment: do you have a segue set for vc?

Comment: I dont think so not sure what a segue is...How would I go about and do that? Thanks for the response by the way!

Answer (score 0):

Add a Storyboard ID (in this case "view") to the View Controller in your Main Storyboard and then add the following to the file from where you want to call the sidebar from:

```
func sideBarDidSelectButtonAtIndex(index: Int) {

    if index == 0 {

        let storyBoard:UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)

        let showView = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("view") as! ViewController

        self.presentViewController(showUebersicht, animated:true, completion:nil)

    }

}
```

Value "0" stands for the first item in the sidebar. Change the value for another value of the array where the items of the sidebar are stored.